# Possible way to emulate multiple game controllers through USB

Tags: emulation

I'm trying to figure out if I can emulate 1 or more game controllers through 1 USB connection.
I want to use a Raspberry Pi and I don't really know what I need to use or get.

If anyone knows then please let me know haha. ty :)